# Please don't call Beijing "Peking"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

[careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Beijing%2C+China) seems to think that Beijing is spelt Peking:

[image]

That's a pretty old and (by now) entirely dated term, and it should probably be corrected to Beijing. I'm not sure if this is the fault of the job poster or the system, but the job ads themselves say Beijing.

Comment: Hmm, looks to me SE got this right but the job advertisers did not.  Don't apply.

Comment: The lack of a red, free-hand cycle in the screenshot made me not to upvote the question :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because the job poster entered 'Peking, China' when they created the listing. I've informed our support team who will get in contact with the customer and get them to update it.

**UPDATE** Jobs have now been changed to [Beijing](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Beijing&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles).